# Forcing one element below another?

Tags: html, css, layout

My basic layout is this:

```
<table>
...
</table>
<table>
...
</table> // There's actually five tables, but that's irrelevant
<img .../>
</body>
```

I'm trying to make the image into a footer, below all the tables, but the best I can manage is that it gets stuck to the right of the tables (my screen is large, so it might wrap around below the tables for you, but not for me) or I can get it to float right on top of the tables by using position:absolute. I cannot for the life of me get the image to be forcibly wrapped below the tables.

I've tried wrapping the image in a div and added all sorts of combinations of attributes/properties to the div, but like I said, they all produce one of the two bad results listed above.

Can anyone offer some sort of solution?

I've seen some other SO questions like [How to force div to appear below not next to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492873/how-to-force-div-to-appear-below-not-next-to-another), but I don't understand that solution at all (how would float:left force something to be below something else?) and I'm also not convinced that the solution requires an extra wrapper `<div>`.

Comment: Have you tried using a div wrapper? You should read about inline vs. block elements.

Comment: @Everyone who's answered/commented: I already had the image as part of this class: `img.center { display: block; margin-left: auto;           margin-right: auto; }`; this was what made the image float in the center, but it still didn't wrap around.

Comment: However, thanks for all the pointers to the clear CSS property. That's one I had not found on my own. I'll add it to the img class and see what happens. PS: Using the `<div>` is not necessary, the `clear: both` can be added directly to the `<img>` tag to get the desired effect.

Comment: And that worked! Thanks, guys! Upvotes for all answers mentioning `clear: both`, and the check mark goes to the guy with the least rep. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<div>
<table>
...
</table>
<table>
...
</table>

</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
<img .../>
</div>

</body>
```

or use css. and create a style for the img or div tag.

Answer (score 9):

Right after the last div containing a table, just add :

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

And it works :) Your divs are using `float: left` therefore you have to put a div telling it to stop all this floating !

Comment: Actually, the page had no divs at all, and no float property specified for any tag.

Comment: Well, inspect your code with Chrome of firebug and you'll see it does :) I suspect your JS library to do it for you though

Comment: Okay, true, the JS was wrapping a div around each table individually. I guess what I meant was that I didn't use any div tags myself. Stupid humans :D

Comment: I believe you, plus analyzing the html source (CTRL+U) reveals you're indeed right. It also shows that JS librairies can do a lot of things without us knowing about it!

Comment: Well actually I did know about it in this case; if you look at the CSS I've actually added some properties to the `dataTables_wrapper` class, which is the div the JS wraps the tables in. Like I said, stupid humans and their imprecision ;)

Answer (score 4):

Apply the following style to the image.

```
<img style="display:block;clear:both;" .../>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with css. Add a class to your image and then change it to block, or clear floats. For example,

HTML:

```
<img src="" class="my-img" />
```

CSS:

```
.my-img
{
display:block;
/*Or*/
clear:both;
}
```